# Melting a data.frame by collapsing two differently named columns into one

Tags: r

I'd like to turn this:

```
   game_date  team_id  opponent_id team_away team_outcome   opponent_outcome
1 2016-03-09    a           b     FALSE          loss              win

  structure(list(game_date = "2016-03-09", team_id = "a", opponent_id = "b", 
team_away = FALSE, team_outcome = "loss", opponent_outcome = "win"), .Names = c("game_date", 
"team_id", "opponent_id", "team_away", "team_outcome", "opponent_outcome"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Into this:

```
game_date     team outcome   away
2016-03-09     a     loss   FALSE
2016-03-09     b     win    TRUE
```

I'm having trouble determining the best way to do this with `reshape`. I've tried for example

```
dcast(x, team_id + opponent_id ~ team_outcome)
melt(x, id.vars = c("team_id", "opponent_id"), measure.vars = c("team_outcome", "team_away")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: There's some extra logic that needs to happen after the reshape so I think it's different enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reshape you could do:

```
y=melt(x,id=c("game_date","team_id","opponent_id","team_away")
    ,measure.vars=c("team_outcome","opponent_outcome"))
```

To get:

```
   game_date team_id opponent_id team_away         variable value
1 2016-03-09       a           b     FALSE     team_outcome  loss
2 2016-03-09       a           b     FALSE opponent_outcome   win
```

Then these to get your desired columns:

```
y$team=ifelse(y$variable == "team_outcome","a","b")
y$away=ifelse(y$variable == "team_outcome" & y$team_away == FALSE,"yes","no")
z=y[,c("game_date","team","value","away")]
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured there'd be an `ifelse` in there somewhere but was probably over-complicating it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it in base R but still curious if there's a melt/reshape/dcast way.

```
all_outcomes<-data.frame(c(x$team_id, x$opponent_id), 
c(x$team_outcome, x$opponent_outcome), 
c(x$team_away, !x$team_away), 
c(x$game_date))
```

Comment: You ought to use the capacity of data.frame to accept column names.

Comment: Yea true, I ended up renaming the columns after, but definitely easier and less lines of code to do it in the same statement.